# How can I set a NSTimer based on what button is pressed?

Tags: ios, nstimer

I have a game where I set a timer.

```
-(void)setTimer{
self->mTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self   selector:@selector(buttonNotPushed) userInfo: nil repeats:NO];
}

-(void)resetTimer{
[self->mTimer invalidate];
self->mTimer = nil;
}
```

Currently, when a user hits the Play button, the timer will be 5 seconds. There are other buttons which every time they are pressed I run

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {

if ([condition]) {
[self resetTimer];
[self setTimer];
}
else ([self gameOver]);
}
```

I would like to create a practice/kid mode where the timer is 10 seconds. Is there a shorter way I can do this besides replicating the whole game again on another viewController and setting the timer?

Comment: By the way, your `buttonPressed` should `resetTimer` first, and then `setTimer`. Also, those `self->` references to deference the ivars are not necessary.

Comment: my mistake.. timer is written as you suggested in my app..messed up here. and thank you for the self. I'll run it later/tomorrow when I'm at my work computer and approve. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using an explicit 5.0 in `setTimer`, create an integer property and reference that. So, create `interval` in your `@interface`

```
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat interval;
```

And then set it to 5.0 or 10.0 as appropriate. And then your `setTimer` is merely:

```
- (void)setTimer {
    mTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:self.interval target:self selector:@selector(buttonNotPushed) userInfo: nil repeats:NO];
}
```